# Self-adjoint elements in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have a simple question which confused me.

Suppose $A$ is a C*-algebra. every $x\in A$ has a representation such as $x=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are self-adjoint elements of $A$. Also we claim that $x^*x$ is self-adjoint while $x^*x$ has the representation $x^*x= a^2+b^2+i(ab-ba)$ which is not self-adjoint in general. I know that it's self-adjoint iff $a,b$ commute. But I think always $a,b$ do not commute. So why do we always say $x^*x$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: $(x^{*}x)^{*} = x^{*}x$ since the conjugate of i is -i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are self-adjoint then so are $a^2 + b^2$ and $i ( ab - ba)$. Let's check the last one:

$$[i(ab - ba)]^* = (-i) ( (ab)^* - (ba)^*) = -i ( b^* a^* - a^* b^*) = -i( b a - a b) = i(ab - ba)$$

Comment: Thanks, exactly it's which I do not notice.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $x^* x$ is clearly self-adjoint since $(x^* x)^* = x^* x^{**} = x^* x$. (Here we just use $x^{**}=x$ and $(xy)^* = y^* x^*$, which are rules in the definition of a $*$-algebra.)

Notice that your expression $x^* x = a^2 + b^2 + i(ab-ba)$ doesn't have the property that $c:=ab-ba$ is self-adjoint, in fact, $c^*=-c$. This implies that $ic$ is self-adjoint and therefore we see again that $x^* x$ is self-adjoint. (But this decomposition is overkill when one wants to check that $x^* x$ is self-adjoint.)

Comment: If you notice I mentioned that $x^*x$ by the representation $a^2+b^2+i(ab-ba)$ is not self-adjoint in general, but we always suppose $x^*x$ is self-adjoint and my question is why dowe say it?

Comment: I think the other answer sorts that out for you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I wanted to indicate why your argument "... which is not self-adjoint in general." was not correct.

Comment: My comment was too cryptic obviously:)

Comment: I image that self-adjoint elements doe not have imaginary part, but it's a counter example for it. so in this case is the spectrum of $x^*x$  a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: It is **not** a counterexample because, as I said, you have not given a decompositon of $x^* x$ as $p+iq$ with $p,q$ self-adjoint. It is correct that $p+iq$, when $p,q$ are self-adjoint, is self-adjoint iff $q=0$, but in your case $q$ is not self-adjoint. But $x^* x$ is always self-adjoint anyway, and there is actually no need to use this decomposition into real and imaginary part. And yes, the spectrum of a self-adjoint element is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes, you are right